# Dividing A Register With 16 Bit Into 8 Bit Two Parts

Tags: cpu-registers

i have encountered some registers in some websites and my textbook. Generally, 16 bit registers are divided into two parts. These two parts with 8 bits are classified L(low) and H(high).

Why is this performed ?

Is it that we work on the 8 bit registers ?

Do these low and high specify an input for utilizing different parts of the register ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cpu you are talking about is from the family of the 8086 processor, yes,  it has 16 bits general purpose registers that could be accessed directly, meaning moving the 16 bits at a time, or loading only one byte (8 bits) to either the lower part of the register (the less meaningull bits), or to the higher part of the register (the mos significant bits).

> Why is this performed ?

I don't know all the reasons but there must be a mix of trade-offs at the time of designing the cpu. Remember that at that time the predecessors of this cpu were 8 bit cpus which could have caused some back compatibility requirements.

> Is it that we work on the 8 bit registers ?

The cpu works with the 16 bits registers but you can address the lower part or the higher part individually.

> Do these low and high specify an input for utilizing different parts
>   of the register ?

Input or output, you could also read their values.